# App doesn't exit from MainLoop after dialog

Tags: dialog, wxwidgets, wxperl

I have this problem.

I have solved, it but does it correct for big application (in future:)?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '.';
use MyApp;
use LoginFrame;

my $f = LoginFrame->new;
$f->ShowModal;
if(int($f->GetReturnCode)) {
    print '['.$f->GetReturnCode."]\n";
    $f->Destroy;

    my $app = new MyApp;
    $app->MainLoop;

} else {
    print "PLEASE NOT THIS CRAP AGAIN!!!\n";
    print '['.$f->GetReturnCode."]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"The ( main ) loop will not terminate until there are top level windows."

- wxPerl tutorial http://wxperl.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial2.html#id4690123